# Do you have to do netilat yadayim for a brief waking?

Tags: halacha, netilat-yadayim-washing, sleep, evening-night

If a person wakes up in the middle of the night to perform a small, brief action (say putting a pacifier back into a baby's mouth) is she required to do netilat yadayim (washing her hands ritually)?

Comment: http://halachahbyemail.blogspot.com/2013/12/netilat-yadayim-if-one-was-awake-all.html#comment-form

Answer (score 2):

I heard once from Rav Willig (senior, of YU) that you do not have to wash netilas yadayim unless you've completed your nights sleep. Don't recall the mekor.

Comment: I recall seeing a Mishna Berura like this, but can't find it now.  It said something along the lines of "and he no longer wishes to sleep", and so I asked my rebbi 'if one gets up, but wants to go back to bed, does he still wash?'